# How to make an infinite (to some n) enumerated list?

Tags: lists, enumerate

What I want is to get something like this:

```
1) 1st item
2) 2nd item
.
.
.
n) nth item
```

But I can't figure it out. `\setcounter{enumi}{n}` doesn't help, as it can only set counter to numbers. Is there any solution within the `enumerate` environment?

Comment: You can insert an item and change its label: `\item[n)] nth item`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `\labelenumii` if the list is nested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item first item
\item second item
\item[$\vdots\;\;$]
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{$n$)}
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{$n$)}
\item $n$th item
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also add `\label` to the last item. If you don't need it, it is simpler to do

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
\item first item
\item second item
\item[$\vdots\;\;$]
\item[$n$)] $n$th item
\end{enumerate}
```